# Can't combine select and plural in ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I am using ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler in my Angular app.
I have a component property initialised in ngOnInit:

`this.translations = { count: this.selections.length, status: this.toStatus };`

and in my lookup strings, I have things like this:

`"markedThing": "Marked {count} thing{count, plural, =0{s} one{} other{s}} as",
"closedSelections": "You've selected {count} thing{count, plural, =0{s} one{} other{s}} to close",`

This all works fine, and trying the 'select' example from [here](https://github.com/lephyrus/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler#example):

`"people": "{gender, select, male{He is} female{She is} other{They are}} {how}",`
 also works fine.

My issue is that when I combine a select and a plural translation the translations break, no errors, just the strings in the app stay as their 'key' versions (like.this).

The one I'm trying to make work is this:

`"markThing": "Mark thing{count, plural, =0{s} one{} other{s}} as {status, select, UNREAD{unread} READ{read} CLOSED{closed}}",`

Any idea what I've done wrong? My template looks like this:

`{{'markThing' | translate:translations}}`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, in a select, an 'other' option is required.